# Find all the rows of between two dates in excel

Tags: excel

I have a single table with all days and also last 7 days in two columns. This I want to
find the highest value in a second table where the rows daily can vary between
one to many.

I have tried to recreated the data here:
[image]

I would like to find the highest day value given the value is above zero.

I have tried variations of index, match but not anything successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for a formula to place in cell I2 in your screenshot that will perform the MAX() function on the correct *dynamic* range of dates in G and H.

There are two approaches to this, and that depends on whether you have Excel O365 / Excel 2021, which gives you access to the FILTER() function.

**WITH Excel O365 or 2021:**

This formula will create a dynamic (in-memory) array of only those Amounts in A2:A22 that match the date range:

*`FILTER(A$2:A$22, (D$2:D$22 >= G2) * (D$2:D$22 <= H2))`*

And thus I just want to take the MAX() of that, and zero.  Which ends up being this formula for I2, which you then copy down:

**`=MAX( 0, FILTER(A$2:A$22, (D$2:D$22 >= G2) * (D$2:D$22 <= H2)) )`**

**Before Excel O365 or Excel 2021:**

You will not have access to the FILTER() function.  Before the FILTER() function, the best practice for this was to use SUMPRODUCT, repeating the same logic that the FILTER() function uses for selecting amounts to include.

*`SUMPRODUCT( A$2:A$22 * (D$2:D$22 >= G2) * (D$2:D$22 <= H2) )`*

will create a 21-row array in memory that will include the 7 desired amounts, and also 14 zeros representing the non-selected amounts.  Which ends up being this formula for I2, which you then copy down:

**`=MAX(SUMPRODUCT( A$2:A$22 * (D$2:D$22 >= G2) * (D$2:D$22 <= H2) )`**

**NOTES:**

- Please note the use of the locked rows ($2 through $22) in the data range, this is important as this formula will be filled down.  Also note the *lack* of locking on the lookup dates in G and H.
- I say this often, the SUMPRODUCT() method of row selecting is *wildly* powerful and a really important advanced Excel skill for people who do these kinds of lookups and filters.  I won't go into detail here, but highly recommend some websites or videos.  Once mastered, you may just stop using the SUMIF/COUNTIF/AVERAGEIF and their related ...IFS ever again.  It allows the complete mixing of nested and/or conditions, where the built-in functions only allow a single level of ANDing.

Comment: Thank you for your help Max. Have been sitting and watching index, match implementations on youtube the whole day. I kept telling myself, this should be possible to be implemented in a easier way, and can see it is possible.

Comment: @random_data_enthutiast happy to help.  Once you start using SUMPRODUCT and binary math to manipulate the selection of numeric data you will never want to go back.  Takes a bit to master but it is excel gold.